# How did Michael end up in that basement in Season 1?

Tags: plot-explanation, fringe

In the last Season of Fringe, the Observer child Michael was essential for the plot. He appeared before in Season 1, where he was found in an abadoned basement.

Is there any explaination how he did end up there? Did anyone bring him there via time travel or is something else possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the episode "The Boy Must Live", September reveals several things:

- At a point in the future, humanity will sacrifice the capacity for emotions for increased intelligence - creating the Observers
- Observers developed techniques for reproducing asexually
- Michael was produced based on September's DNA, technically making him his father
- Michael was born with an abnormality - both Observer-level intelligence and the capacity for emotions, and was to be destroyed
- September decided to hide Michael in the past, to protect him

http://fringe.wikia.com/wiki/The_Boy_Must_Live

How Michael ended up specifically where he was in the original timeline is never explained, to the best of my knowledge. That episode indicated he had been alone for some time, so it's likely September broke contact to protect him.